# Is XAML idea first pioneered by Microsoft?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mxml, history, markup

I have come across [Adobe MXML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f39f-7fff.html) that looks very similar to Microsoft's XAML. Who came up with this idea first? The reason I ask is, when I first saw WPF and the XAML approach, I thought it was a very unique and amazing idea that was never seen before MFC, Winforms, etc, even though I feel it takes some getting used to from the older, more traditional ways.

So just trying to see who pioneered this idea of programming first. I feel like this idea might be older than both companies?

Comment: Which features of xaml are you talking about? Just declarative description on an UI is very old. Other features of xaml are less common elsewhere.

Comment: Microsoft has never pioneered anything, AFAIK.  Except maybe C#. Oh, wait...

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I was looking at the xml style declaration way of designing UIs, etc.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, XAML came in June 2008, MXML came in March 2004. However both are based on XML - more details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_markup_language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "markup" to describe a visual image or text and documents started in the publishing industry (60's and 70's) with publishers needing a way to describe their documents (GML and [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)). This was then used in browsers for the web, now XAML, and on and on.

See [here](http://careo.prn.bc.ca/losc/mod1t1.html) for an explanation.

And an excerpt:

> Standard Generalized Markup Language was the next iteration on GML and was accepted as an ISO standard in 1986. IBM and many other organizations in the technical publishing business such as aeronautics soon used SGML for most of their publishing purposes.
>
> SGML is the mother of all markup languages, but it is extremely complicated and more powerful than needed for most applications. In the late 1980s, Tim Berners-Lee and Robert Caillau were working on the beginnings of the World Wide Web to make it easy to share scholarly information between physicists. They recognized the need for a markup language to facilitate links between documents and for display in a browser, and so HyperText Markup Language (HTML) was born along with the Web in 1991.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the idea of defining the UI in an XML dialect in Mozilla a good number years ago.

The whole UI of the browser uses [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul) and the scripting language is javascript. This was a number of years before XAML came from MS.

Comment: the magic of WPF/XAML is the data binding though - any earlier examples for that part?

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I wouldn't know. The OP didn't really say which part of XAML/MXML he was talking about. I assumed that he meant representing the UI in markup and using scripting to control it.

Comment: Databinding in ASP/ASP.NET.  No technology is truly unique, have you seen the chart at http://www.levenez.com/lang/lang_a4.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

There are some more:

[List of user interface markup languages](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_interface_markup_languages)

Answer (score 1):

GTK did this ages ago :

Glade Interface Designer = Initial release April 18, 1998

XAML  = Initial release v1.0 / June 2008[1]

Just a thought